# Rewrite Rule not working for Ionics Isapi Rewrite filter

Tags: regex, iirf

I have following rule in my IIRF.ini. We need to kill this pages now and so i have to give 410 to them.

```
RewriteRule  ^(?i)/index.aspx?puid=99AE83F8-D3E6-4F96-88B1-41C8A625D073 - [L]
RewriteRule  ^(?i)/index.aspx?puid=B6F16F09-859A-4ABA-9D6B-53CB4BE7AE62 - [L]
RewriteRule  ^(?i)/index.aspx?puid=0295D08A-8645-4D8B-9D1E-E291127120FD - [L]
```

But when i apply rule like

```
RewriteRule  ^(?i)/index.aspx?puid=2369474A-950C-4A24-A73E-8EF5F149CB95 /Error.aspx [G]
```

it didn't work and still hitting this pages? Is there anything special i have to do as it has query string parameters?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Redirect every single request to index.aspx to Error.aspx ?

Comment: Trying to give 410 to each of this links

Answer (score 0):

The expression is regex - you have to escape the ? character - i.e.

```
 RewriteRule  ^(?i)/index.aspx[?]puid=2369474A-950C-4A24-A73E-8EF5F149CB95 /Error.aspx [G,I]
```

Also changing [G] to [G,I] for enforcing "ignore case sensitivity".